# Sql query slowness due to rank and columns with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**EDITED:**

I have the following table in database with around **10 millions** records:

**Declaration:**

```
create table PropertyOwners (
    [Key] int not null primary key,
    PropertyKey int not null, 
    BoughtDate DateTime, 
    OwnerKey int null, 
    GroupKey int null
)
go
```

[Key] is primary key and combination of PropertyKey, BoughtDate, OwnerKey and GroupKey is unique.

**With the following index:**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PropertyOwners] ON [dbo].[PropertyOwners] 
(
    [PropertyKey] ASC,
    [BoughtDate] DESC,
    [IsGroup] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [OwnerKey], [GroupKey])
go
```

**Description of the case:**

For single BoughtDate one property can belong to multiple owners or single group, for single record there can either be OwnerKey or GroupKey but not both so one of them will be null for each record. I am trying to retrieve the data from the table using following query for the OwnerKey. If there are same property rows for owners and group at the same time than the rows having OwnerKey with be preferred, that is why I am using "IsGroup" in Rank function.

```
declare @ownerKey int = 40000
select PropertyKey, BoughtDate, OwnerKey, GroupKey
from (  
    select PropertyKey, BoughtDate, OwnerKey, GroupKey,
        RANK() over (partition by PropertyKey order by BoughtDate desc, IsGroup) as [Rank]
    from PropertyOwners
) as result
where result.[Rank]=1 and result.[OwnerKey]=@ownerKey
```

It is taking 2-3 seconds to get the records when ever I use the [Rank]=1 with any of PropertyKey/OwnerKey/GroupKey. But when I tried to get the records for the PropertyKey/OwnerKey/GroupKey without using [Rank]=1 in the same query, it is executing in milliseconds. See following query:

```
declare @ownerKey int = 40000
select PropertyKey, BoughtDate, OwnerKey, GroupKey
from (  
    select PropertyKey, BoughtDate, OwnerKey, GroupKey,
        RANK() over (partition by PropertyKey order by BoughtDate desc, IsGroup) as [Rank]
    from PropertyOwners
) as result
where result.[OwnerKey]=@ownerKey
```

I have also tried to use the Indexed view to pre ranked them but I can't use it in my query as Rank function is not supported in indexed view.

Please note this table is updated once a day and using Sql Server 2008 R2. Any help will be 
greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried moving the where clause for owner key to the inner query?

Comment: I can't do that as I want to apply this check after getting all the latest property information from the table. If I will apply it in the inner query then it will be wrong as query will retieve the record for that owner even that property doesn't belong to it now.

Comment: Is it possible to have 2 rows for the same `PropertyKey` and `BoughtDate`, but with different `OwnerKey`s that are both not NULL?

Comment: @Ennor Yes its possible to have 2 or more distinct OwnerKey(s) for same PropertyKey and BoughtDate.

Comment: @FaheemRamzan, in this case the owner with least ID value will never be returned, because (s)he will have rank 2 for the given property and date. If it's unacceptable, I would recommend to rework the table structure.

Comment: @Ennor, very good that you found a bug in my query. I have reworked the the table structure and index. Now have bit column name IsGroup with will be false for the rows I have OwnerKey(s). Please see my edited question and thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your query correctly, it basically does as follows: "for a given owner, return all properties for which this owner is the latest one".

This can also be achieved in other ways, without ranking the entire 10M table, such as:

```
select po.*
from dbo.PropertyOwners po
where po.OwnerKey = @OwnerKey
  and not exists (
  select 0 from dbo.PropertyOwners lo
  where lo.PropertyKey = po.PropertyKey
  and lo.BoughtDate > po.BoughtDate
  -- Other group-related conditions here, if need be
  );
```

Essentially the same, just a little bit different wording:

```
select po.*
from dbo.PropertyOwners po
  left join dbo.PropertyOwners lo on lo.PropertyKey = po.PropertyKey
  and lo.BoughtDate > po.BoughtDate
  -- Other group-related conditions here, if need be
where po.OwnerKey = @OwnerKey
  and lo.PropertyKey is null;
```

You will definitely need different indices for these, and I can't be sure they will help. But at least give it a try.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. This is just amazing how you solve this problem in such an easy way and it made the query to execute in only 1 millisecond :)

Comment: Can you help me with following question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488607/sql-server-which-is-better-rank-or-left-join-with-own-table-to-filter-latest)