# Sql server which is better "Rank" or "Left join with own table" to filter latest records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table in database with around 10 millions records (it will increase in future may be double in 1 year):

```
create table PropertyOwners (
    [Key] int not null primary key,
    PropertyKey int not null, 
    BoughtDate DateTime, 
    OwnerKey int not null
)
go
```

Above table contains all the property owned by an owner at certain time, I want to get the owners which owns more than certain amount of properties at a current time, lets say more then 1000 properties at a time. I have written two different queries one using "Rank" and other using "Left join with own table".

**Using Rank (Taking around 4 sec):**

```
select OwnerKey, COUNT(1) PropertyCount 
from (
    select PropertyKey, OwnerKey, BoughtDate,
        RANK() over (partition by PropertyKey order by BoughtDate desc) as [Rank]
    from dbo.PropertyOwners 
) result
where [Rank]=1
group by OwnerKey
having COUNT(1)>1000
```

Using left join with same table (Taking around 10sec):

```
select OwnerKey, COUNT(1) PropertyCount 
from (
    select po.PropertyKey, po.OwnerKey, po.BoughtDate
    from dbo.PropertyOwners po
    left join dbo.PropertyOwners lo on lo.PropertyKey = po.PropertyKey
    and lo.BoughtDate > po.BoughtDate
    where lo.PropertyKey is null
) result
group by OwnerKey
having COUNT(1)>1000
```

Both of the query times are unacceptable as taking so much time, can anyone help me with the query to rewrite. My table has following index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PropertyKey_BounghtDate] ON [dbo].[PropertyOwners] 
(
    [PropertyKey] ASC,
    [BoughtDate] DESC
)
INCLUDE ( [OwnerKey]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Review your query plans. It might not be using your index at all. Also, Your left join query looks very odd. Please explain what the relationship table actually means - doing a self join doesn't seem to make sense. And why on earth is there a [Key] field when you have a PropertyKey and OwnerKey - the combination of those should be your primary key (unless you have a start/end date for ownership)...

Comment: It looks like you built a nonclustered index on a fairly unique set of fields, which is likely not being used by this query given the aggregation.  A non-clustered index on `PropertyKey` may improve performance, but the execution plan should give you all the insight you need.  Analytic/window functions are typically faster than introducing additional joins to a query.

Comment: We can ignore the [Key] field, combination of PropertyKey, OnwerKey, and BoughtDate is unique and can be composite PK. I have checked the execution plan, query is using "Index scan" instead of "Index seek". I have tried my best by trying different index combination but with no success, that is why I asked question here. And the left join query is selecting the records per property and taking the latest for each property using the BoughtDate check.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite this as (which might improve performance)

```
select OwnerKey, COUNT(1) PropertyCount 
from (
    select PropertyKey, MAX( BoughtDate) BoughtDate
    from dbo.PropertyOwners 
    Group by PropertyKey
) result INNER JOIN dbo.PropertyOwners po ON po.PropertyKey=result.PropertyKey and PO.boughtDate=result.boughtdate
group by OwnerKey
having COUNT(1)>1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a fair amount of data and a lot that has to be counted.  [This](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) analysis by Aaron Bertrand isn't exactly your problem, but it might help you.

With your supporting index, I would recommend trying the `not exists` approach:

```
select OwnerKey, count(*) as PropertyCount
from PropertyOwners po
where not exists (select 1
                  from PropertyOwners po2
                  where po2.PropertyKey = po.PropertyKey and
                        po2.BoughtDate > po.BoughtDate
                 )
group by OwnerKey
having count(*) > 1000;
```

If you can't get the query to work sufficiently fast, you may need to either upgrade your hardware or use triggers to keep a summary table up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is never fast. You may look into indices that SQL Server will suggest if you run your queries sufficient amount of times; google diagnostic queries that involve `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`, they will be of some help.

Another option, already suggested before, is building a summary table. Slightly more lightweight solution will be an indexed view, but you have to understand implications that will come into play if you will create it.